# Create a new file and add new values in unix

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I want to read a file and I want to generate a new file that includes all unique variables in column X of the original file in alphabetical order.

```
Dataframe1 Example:
|ID|Var1|Var2|Var3|
|:--|:----:|:----:|:----:|
|A|9|45.50|AAAAAAA|
|B|20|89.99|ZZZZZZZ|
|C|5|14.50|AAAAAAA|
|D|11|15.50|ABCDEFG|
|E|9|50.99|ABCDEFG|

Desired file output:
AAAAAAA
ABCDEFG
ZZZZZZZ
```

```
   awk -v File1=/pathway 'BEGIN{comm="cat "File1; while(comm|getline){array[1]=$Var4;}{if()}... > Output.txt
```

I am stuck honestly afterwards. Please help.

Comment: At this point, why not use a modern scripting language like python or ruby?

Comment: Because my script is all in unix and this is the part I am missing. I will convert to python at a later date.

Comment: I think `awk 'NR>2{print $NF}' file | sort -u` should give you the requred output. (python is great, but learn the basics (-;! Work your way thru [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) ). Good luck. to all.

Comment: @shellter lmao thanks this is exactly what I needed. If you want an upvote for the answer, post as the solution.

Comment: Tnx, Glad to hear that helped. If someone cares to write a fuller description, give them the up vote (or do it yourself after reading the tutorial and give yourself the upvote (-;! . Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

you use SED and CUT as below

```
sed '2d' <filename>| cut -d"|" -f4  |uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    BEGIN{ out="Output.txt" } 
    NR>2 && NF==6{ a[$(NF-1)] } 
    END{
        n=asorti(a,b); 
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i] > out; 
        close(out)
    }
' Input.txt

$ cat Output.txt
AAAAAAA
ABCDEFG
ZZZZZZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR>2 && !seen[$5]++{print $5}' file
AAAAAAA
ZZZZZZZ
ABCDEFG
```